# Attribute table can't be "unfiltered"

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile, attribute-table, filter

We got a shapefile from someone who is working with ArcMap. For them, the file contains 363 features - for us, when opened in QGIS 3.28.7, the file only contains 321 features. The attribute table states in the header

> total features: 363, filtered: 321

When we add a virtual ID-field, several numbers are omitted, leaving us with 321 IDs, but counting up to 362. There is no filter we can undo, and no other way to make the data visible. When we export the data, or modify the attribute table, only 321 features are saved. Screenshots provided by someone else working with Arc show that those 42 features actually exist.

I am wondering, what the reason for this discrepancy could be, as well as if and how it can be remedied using QGIS.

Comment: Could the ArcMap user export the shapefile again, possibly into GeoPackage format? Of course shapefile should be OK but there is probably something unusual going on.

Comment: might be a bug. If there are entries without a geometry, they would appear when opening the attribute table (must be "show all features" by default) but not if touching the "show ..." button, so if set to "show visible on map" by default it will never work. Creating a virtual layer returning all rows of the layer works though

Comment: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/55065

Comment: You're really sure no provider feature filter is applied?

Comment: @Babel yes, there's no filter.

Comment: @user30184 sure, we'll try that avenue - once the creator of the data is back from vacation. It could be the features have been left out intentionally.